# how to GET request from an api in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, angular2-observables, angular-httpclient

I'm trying to get the JSON using `HttpClient` in Angular 7. The code works fine but I'm trying to implement the commented lines to get the data directly from the API url and stop using the `const IMAGES`.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class ImageService {

  // public _url: string = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos";
  constructor(
    // public http: HttpClient
  ) {}

  theImages = [];
  // IMAGES = [];
  getImages(){
    // this.IMAGES = this.http.get(this._url);
   return this.theImages = IMAGES.slice(0);
 }
  getImage(id: number){
    // this.IMAGES = this.http.get(this._url);
    return IMAGES.slice(0).find(image => image.id == id);
  }

}
const IMAGES = [
  {
    "albumId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt",
    "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/92c952",
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/92c952"
  },
...
```

error code is:

```
error TS2740: Type 'Observable<Object>' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 25 more.
```

Comment: the http method will return observable, better you read the documentation first [guide to http](https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-json-data)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to return from the methods an `Observable`
and then subscribe to the `ImageService` instance's methods returned data.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class ImageService {

  public _url: string = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos";

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {}

  getImages() {
   return this.http.get(this._url);
 }

  getImage(id: number) {
    return this.http.get(this._url)
                    .pipe(first(item => item.id === id));
  }

}
```

From another place in your project

```
...
imageService.getImages().subscribe(images => /*...*/)
...
```

Comment: An interesting note here is that `HttpClient` won't action the `.get` request until it is subscribed to.